# Model vs Axiom vs Theory... difference

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I am not a student but I am interested in logic, I am reading a book about model theory. The problem is I guess book is not so interested in defining notions and I also couldn't understand the definitions in the internet. So I want to start from the beginning:

As I understand conjugations atomic sentences make bigger sentences and their truth value is an "assignment". A set of sentences is called a theory and if another set of sentences can "semanticly" (*isn't deriving something a syntatic task?) derive all sentences of that theory it is a model of that theory. And there is axioms that are have the same "consequence" (*what does this means?) of their theory. And can model also be axioms? What does it mean set of sentences to be "increasing"? And what does it mean a sentence to be "positive"?

I hope these questions doesn't sound ridiculous...

Comment: There are too many questions. A model is not a set of sentences, it is a structure. Instead of starting with a book on model theory, an introduction to logic seems like it would be more in order.

Comment: See e.g. [What's a Logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3376593/whats-a-logic) and [Interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339624/connection-between-interpretation-variable-assignment-and-truth-valuation) adn [Structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015238/having-trouble-in-understanding-fol-structure) and [Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3119403/a-question-on-the-formality-of-a-theory).

Comment: What book are you reading?

Answer (score 3):

This question -- or rather, very muddled bundle of questions -- strongly suggests that you are trying to run before you can walk.

Before tackling model theory, you absolutely need to get a firm grasp of first-order logic.

There are some wonderful books on FOL out there. For some suggestions to explore, to find what will work best for you, see the chapter on FOL in *Beginning Mathematical Logic: A Study Guide* which you can download from https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl